# Listbox. How to increase the height item?

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to increase the height of the item, but I can not.
I use the `listBox1_DrawItem` and`listBox1_MeasureItem` events.
**Code.**

```
    private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
            {
                e.DrawBackground();
                e.DrawFocusRectangle();

                // You'll change the font size here. Notice the 20
                // e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Index, new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 20, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(e.Index), e.Bounds);

                //e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString,
                //                     listBox1.Font, Brushes.Black,
                //                     e.Bounds.Left, (
                //                     (e.Bounds.Height - listBox1.Font.Height)) + e.Bounds.Top);

                // e.DrawBackground(); //Draw our regular background

                // e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 1, listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString().Length - 1), e.Font, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds);    //Draw the item text in red!

                // e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds); //Draw the item text in its regular color

                    // e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 1, listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString().Length - 1), e.Font, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds);    //Draw the item text in red!

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds); //Draw the item text in its regular color



            }

            private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
            {
                e.ItemHeight = 25;
            }
public void InfoError()
        {
            string info = "Ошибка";
            listBox1.ItemHeight = 60; 

            listBox1.Items.Add(info);
        }

          public void InfoSuccess()
            {
                string info = "Успех";
                listBox1.Items.Add(info);

            }
     // Ошибка
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                InfoError();
            }

            // Успех
            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                InfoSuccess();
            }
```

Question.
1. Increase the "item" height (item) or the distance between "item"?

Comment: Where are you calling the function? Listbox has a maximum height I believe, so that may be your issue if you are exceeding that with the items.

Comment: @JacobH Updated the question.
I answered your question?

Comment: `listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;`

Comment: Do you mean, you want to change the Item height **on the fly**? Setting different values after the controls has beed created and an `ItemHeight` value has been set? If this is the case, see the [`WM_MEASUREITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-measureitem) message.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
// Set the DrawMode property to the OwnerDrawVariable value. 
// This means the MeasureItem and DrawItem events must be 
// handled.
ListBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
ListBox1.MeasureItem += new MeasureItemEventHandler(ListBox1_MeasureItem);
```

You need to change the DrawMode in order to call the MeasureEvent where you will update the listbox height.